# Post edit that didn't change a single character

Tags: bug

I had an edit to my post that appears to not have changed a single character.

[catalog_product_load_before event gives getRequestedRouteName() error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112973/catalog-product-load-before-event-gives-getrequestedroutename-error#112973)

It is the edit made by Amit Bera at 3:42 PM ET. Am I going crazy, or was nothing edited?

Comment: goose do not fill crazy.it is formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something was edited. Take a look at the [revisions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/112973/revisions). 2 ` characters were added to format the code.

Comment: ya,marius i was just do a simple formatting.Does not know  why @Goose fell Crazy